# How to fill the missing months in an array with zero?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to fill missing months in an array with zeros. I have an array like below

```
dashCustomerData = [{
    "req_count": 1,
    "revenue": 11868.19,
    "getMonth": "August",
    "count(compID)": 2
  },
  {
    "req_count": 1,
    "revenue": 942.82,
    "getMonth": "January",
    "count(compID)": 1
  },
  {
    "req_count": 0,
    "revenue": null,
    "getMonth": "May",
    "count(compID)": 0
  },
  {
    "req_count": 1,
    "revenue": 28367.31,
    "getMonth": "October",
    "count(compID)": 2
  }
]
```

Now i want to add missing months in this array with `req_count` as 0. I tried doing that by having a months array and looping through it

```
var allmonths = [
  'April',
  'May',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'September',
  'October',
  'November',
  'December',
  'January',
  'February',
  'March'
];

var customers = [];

$.each(dashCustomerData, function(index) {
  var thisMonth = (dashCustomerData[index].getMonth);
  var thisCount = (dashCustomerData[index].req_count);
  $.each(allmonths, function(index) {
    test = 0;
    if (thisMonth == allmonths[index])
      customers.push(thisCount);
    else
      customers.push('0');
  })

});
```

But it is looping through all the months for all the records. Can I just add zero only for one month?

Comment: What is `customers`? Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Customers is an empty array. In which i am pushing the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i want to add missing months in this array with req_count as 0

You can loop over `allmonths` and in each iteration, find the corresponding entry in `dashCustomerData`. If it is not found, then push a new entry with `req_count` as `0` to `dashCustomerData`.

Check the demo below:

```js
const dashCustomerData = [{"req_count":1,"revenue":11868.19,"getMonth":"August","count(compID)":2},{"req_count":1,"revenue":942.82,"getMonth":"January","count(compID)":1},{"req_count":0,"revenue":null,"getMonth":"May","count(compID)":0},{"req_count":1,"revenue":28367.31,"getMonth":"October","count(compID)":2}];
const allmonths = ['April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November','December','January','February','March'];

let result = [];

allmonths.forEach(month => {
  const item = dashCustomerData.find(item => item.getMonth === month);
  
  if (item) {
    result.push(item);
  } else {
    result.push({getMonth: month, req_count: 0});
  }
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works can I have the months in order like all months?

Comment: Hey @31piy can I sort the months in the allmonths order as i am sending that data to a c3 graph and I need it sorted. I tried different ways but was not able to find a solution...

Comment: @Sourav -- please see my updated answer. The simplest fix would be to push items to a new array. That way, the order will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can just replace the `null` values with `0` using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object#defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) :

```
data = data.map(e => e.revenue ? e : Object.defineProperty(e, 'revenue', {value: 0}));
```

If `e.revenue` is *truthy*, just keep the object as is, otherwise redefine its `revenue` property to `0`.

***Demo:***

```js
let data = [{"req_count":1,"revenue":11868.19,"getMonth":"August","count(compID)":2},
{"req_count":1,"revenue":942.82,"getMonth":"January","count(compID)":1},
{"req_count":0,"revenue":null,"getMonth":"May","count(compID)":0},
{"req_count":1,"revenue":28367.31,"getMonth":"October","count(compID)":2}];

data = data.map(e => e.revenue ? e : Object.defineProperty(e, 'revenue', {value: 0}));

console.log(data);
```